# SQLite could not insert to table

Tags: android, sqlite

Previous question: I'm following a SQLite tutorial and now I want to add two more columns to the table but there is error now? What is the problem here? Please help.

Logcat:

```
   08-10 15:13:29.077: E/SQLiteLog(17055): (1) table country has no column named add
08-10 15:13:29.082: E/SQLiteDatabase(17055): Error inserting add=Feg dest=Fhd code=5495 cap=Egd name=A
08-10 15:13:29.082: E/SQLiteDatabase(17055): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table country has no column named add (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO country(add,dest,code,cap,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
08-10 15:13:29.082: E/SQLiteDatabase(17055):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-10 15:13:29.082: E/SQLiteDatabase(17055):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1012)
```

My SQLite java class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name, cap, code, dest, add);";     
        db.execSQL(createQuery);        
    }
```

Comment: could you plz paste your insert query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change this

> ```
>  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists countryname(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
>             + " name"
>             + " TEXT ,"
>             + " cape"
>             + " TEXT,"
>             + " code" 
>             + " TEXT,"
>             + " dest" 
>             + " TEXT,"
>             + " mem"
>             +" TEXT);");
> ```

into

> ```
>   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists countryname(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
>             + " name"
>             + " TEXT ,"
>             + " cape"
>             + " TEXT,"
>             + " code" 
>             + " TEXT,"
>             + " dest" 
>             + " TEXT,"
>             + " mem"
>             +" TEXT)");
> ```
>
> you have **;** after TEXT.. then please delete your old db and try it again it will work sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any reserved keyword as the column name. add is a reserved keyword, it can't be used as column name unless you quote it like 'add', "add" , `add` or wrap it in bracket like [add].

Answer (score 0):

Probably because "add" is a [SQLite reserved word](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).  You'll need to quote it, to indicate it's a column name.

```
INSERT INTO country(dest,code,[add],cap,name)
```

From the link, you can actually use any of 'add', "add", [add], or `add`.